# Finales in Camp Grizzly - how do they work?

Tags: camp-grizzly

When you reveal a finale, what happens to counselors who are not present in the finale cabin? Are the turns stopped? Does Otis continue to stalk us?

Do you just follow the rules on the card, ignoring everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any councelors not in the finale cabin wait for the finale to resolve. During the finale no normal turns happen (i.e. "follow the rules on the card, ignoring everything else"). If the finale is failed then they still have a chance to win.  From section 1.4 of [the rules](http://ameritrashgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/TGC_Rules3.pdf):

> The players holding the objectives
> must agree to start the finale during one of their
> move phases (or wait for stragglers)

...and...

> WIN - If the counselors complete the finale card
> successfully, they win!
>
> FAIL - If all counselors involved in a finale fail, that
> finale card is discarded. Any survivors who remain in
> the camp still have a chance to attempt a different
> finale.

So if the finale is won then the game ends (and only the councelors who complete the finale win), but if no councelors survive the finale then any "stragglers" (players not involved) may carry on.

Comment: Does that mean that even if a councelor is not in the finale, but the players pass it, they are considered "winners", or it simply means that the players involved in the finale win, but the other players have yet another chance to escape?

This doesn't answer the question whether Otis and player's turns are carried on as normally during a finale. Do you simply follow the card's instructions, ignoring the normal 3-turn phase? (Moving, Cabin Draw phase, End Turn)

Comment: I've updated the answer to try to be clearer about these two points. I don't think the rules are 100% clear about whether another finale may be attempted after the first has been won, but given the formatting (camp survivors only mentioned in the FAIL section) and thematically (there's only one finale to this genre of story) then this makes sense.  FWIW This reviewer also agrees with the assumption that stragglers lose the game (~26 mins in): https://boardgamegeek.com/video/48309/camp-grizzly/undeadviking-videos-camp-grizzly-review-most-fun-g